# How can I find out where a particular item is being stored in a riak cluster?

Tags: mapreduce, riak

I have a Riak cluster which is used to store images and I would like to be able to know where the each image is being stored in the cluster.

Given a key for the image, I would like to return a list of server IP addresses that are currently holding a copy of the image. I've checked through the documentation and I'm unable to find anything that would let me do this. Is there a simple way in which I can do this either through the Riak command line tools or by writing a mapreduce function?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to know this information?

Comment: I'd like to do it to understand a little bit about where the data is and be able to prove to others that the data replication is working. As a 'relatively' new technology, I find it interesting to understand what's happening to the data that we store in a cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this is not exposed via any public documented interface, but I just did a small research on this topic and found the recepie to get this information:

1. Connect to Riak node with CLI command **riak attach**
2. Execute the following command:

   riak_core_apl:get_apl(chash:key_of(?KEY), 3, riak_kv).

The **?KEY** is the key of object that needs to be located. In response you will get the list of Riak nodes responsible for specified object, including their IPs or hostnames.

Hope this helps :)